# Two Dockerfiles share resources built by common build container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that builds some webpack stuff:

```
FROM node:21 as assets
COPY ...
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

That produces a dist directory with roughly the following content:

```
webpack-stats.json
bundle.js
bundle.css
```

Now i have two Containers that need the result:

```
FROM python:latest
COPY --from=assets /app/dist/webpack-stats.json .
CMD python ...
```

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=assets /app/dist/ .
CMD nginx ...
```

However, those can't be put in the same Dockerfile, since one Dockerfile only builds one image / container.
I also want to avoid running the build container twice to avoid inconsistency and long  build times.

Is there a way to built only once, but use it in two containers?

Comment: To give some context: the python container is a django application, that needs the stat file for django-webpack-loader, which puts the right <script> tags in the template. The nginx container then serves those static files directly and proxys the rest to the django application

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to built only once, but use it in two containers?

So tag it.

```
/assets/Dockefile
    FROM node:21 as assets
    COPY ...
    RUN npm install
    RUN npm run build
/app1/Dockerfile
    FROM assets AS assets
    FROM python:latest
    COPY --from=assets /app/dist/webpack-stats.json .
    CMD python ...
```

And then build with

```
cd assets
docker build -t assets .
cd ..
cd app1
docker build .
```

"Professionally" you would publish assets from a separate CI/CD into a private docker repository, like for example to gitlab project container registry, and use the full name in depende dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

This is why people have Docker Hub accounts. I didn't try this, just rolled off the fingers.

In one directory you have Dockerfile containing

```
FROM node:21 as assets
COPY ...
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

Now

```
docker login
docker build --pull -t <yourdockerusername>/mybasebuild .
docker push <yourdockerusername>/mybasebuild
```

Now in a different directory you have a Dockerfile containing this

```
FROM mybasebuild as Builder
FROM python:latest
COPY --from=Builder /app/dist/webpack-stats.json .
CMD python ...
```

in case you logged out

```
docker login
docker build --pull -t <yourdockerusername>/mylittlepython .
docker push <yourdockerusername>/mylittlepython
```

In a third directory you have a Dockerfile containing this

```
FROM mybasebuild as Builder
FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=assets /app/dist/ .
CMD nginx ...
```

If you logged out of docker log back in and

```
docker build --pull -t <yourdockerusername>/mylittleinx .
docker push <yourdockerusername>/mylittleinx
```